# How could one determine the maximum character count in an XML file conforming to a given schema?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, xsd

I need to determine the theoretical maximum character count, including tags, of an XML file conforming to a given XSD schema and am simply blanking on how one might go about that. I am open to XSLT based solutions or any of the .NET XML methods.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try so far? What do you mean by 'theoretical maximum'? Is there an upper bound?

Comment: This depends on the schema, any repeating elements, cdata etc mean that there is no maximum - so you would now be talking fs and memory limits here.

Comment: I think there are probably very few schemas in the wild that do not allow an unlimited amount of content, so the answer will nearly always be "infinity".

Comment: These are all fair points and along the line of what I was thinking, but basically I was trying to determine if there was a way to figure out a maximum character count assuming all my nodes occurred with maximal length and a maximal number of times (excepting any unbounded nodes of course). I started trying to dig into the .net schema object, to pull out the schema facets etc. but if you've tried this you know that doing anything other than supplying a schema to a validator is a huge PITA. Just wondering if anyone else had tried to do something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The *theoretical* maximum character count is unlimited.**

An XML file that conforms to a schema that only allows a restricted set of content could still contain lots of comments, processing instructions, declared (but unused) namespaces, and entities.

All of those things would contribute to the character count of the XML instance file and are beyond the constraints of the XSD.